# NSPredicate fails with BOOL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I try to filter an array of objects that have `@property BOOL` missed
depending on the value of this property

I defined:

```
NSPredicate *missedInvitationsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(CRGQuizInvitation* invitation, NSDictionary *bind){
    return invitation.missed == YES;
}];
```

but it fails. I tried a lot of things like using predicateWithFormat, one equal sign and many others. at the end I solved it by converting the `BOOL` to `NSNumber`, but I still want to know what's wrong with that.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? Do you get an exception? If you do, please add it to the question.

Comment: fails = doesn't get the appropriate results. doesn't throw an exception. 
to be more specific, the code in the block (i.e. return invitation.missed == YES;) returns false whether i compare to YES or NO. that's the weird thing

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it without converting to `NSNumber`.Here is the sample code.

```
NSMutableArray *collection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < 5; itemIndex++)
{
  CRGQuizInvitation *invitation = [[CRGQuizInvitation alloc] init];

  if (itemIndex %2 == 0)
  {
    invitation.missed = YES;
  }

  [collection addObject:invitation];
}

NSPredicate *missedInvitationsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(CRGQuizInvitation* invitation, NSDictionary *bind){
    return invitation.missed == YES;
}];

NSArray *trueValueObjCollection = [collection filteredArrayUsingPredicate: missedInvitationsPredicate];

NSLog(@"%@", trueValueObjCollection);
```

**CRGQuizInvitation**

```
@interface CRGQuizInvitation : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL missed;

@end
```

**Output Log**

```
<TestClass: 0x8f1d450>
<TestClass: 0x8f1e440>
<TestClass: 0x8f1e460>
```

Comment: i tried using [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == YES"]; already but it fails. 
i converted to NSNumber to solve it, but i want to know what am i doing wrong when using BOOL directly